# How to send multiple response for single request in .net core api 1

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azureservicebus

I have scenario where client request data by api and response contains 1000 records but client can accept only 100 records.

How can we send multiple response for single request in .net core api 1?

Any solution using Azure also fine.
Please guide.

Comment: Web API is being used by multiple applications, some can have 100 records and some can 200 so a constant page size is not suitable.

Comment: Don’t use a constant page size - allow the client to specify it using e.g. a query-string parameter.

Comment: In short, you cannot: one request = one response. Your endpoint should accept page number and page size params, and then your API response should contain links for first/last, current, and next/previous, as per REST guidelines (HATEOAS, see: https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/)

Comment: @ChrisPratt Your comment/answer creates more problems than it solves - how do you ensure consistent snapshot  which would have been there if you just could split the result dataset over multiple responses? If the underlying data changes while client queries for more pages, you will get a catdog instead of meaningful data.